# Configuring Rails Instances: adding methods to Model Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to make a *singular* permissions file that can add instance methods to a bunch of classes in rails.

basically, I'll expose a class method "grant_permission(foo,bar)" and then, all in the same permissions.rb

```
Admin.grant_permission(:Admin,:Create)
Login.grant_permission(:Admin,:Index)
Viewer.grant_permission(:Stuff,:Index)
Admin.grant_permission(:Stuff,:Create)
```

ect. I'd love for this 'permissions.rb' file to live in the 'config' folder, but the big question is how do I add such files to run when the server starts up?

Please note: i'm not asking how to write the grant_permissions class, I'm asking how to add 'permissions.rb' file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializers which live in `/config/initializers/` are automatically run when rails starts up.

Comment: If forgot to come back to this question, but this is exactly where I put it. Thanks!